# xmlgregoriancalendar formatting in MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: java, xml, date, formatting

I have a variable  of type date in the format `MM/dd/yyyy`. I need to convert the tempdate to xmlgregoriancalendar type in the same format i.e., `MM/dd/yyyy`.

The default format when created using `newxmlgregoriancalendarDate()` is `yyyy-MM-dd`
so i am unable to convert it to `MM/dd/yyyy` format of type xmlgregoriancalendar

how to acheive this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`XMLGregorianCalendar` doesn't really "have" a format - or rather, it's not part of the data in the object, because the XML format for dates/times is [specified](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime-order) in a particular format. So the request of "I need to convert the tempdate to xmlgregoriancalendar type in the same format i.e., MM/dd/yyyy" makes no sense, really.

If you want to get a different textual representation *as a string*, I suggest you use [`toGregorianCalendar()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toGregorianCalendar%28%29) to get a `java.util.Calendar` - then you can get the `java.util.Date` and use an appropriately constructed `SimpleDateFormat` to do the formatting.