# Formats for XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: date

I am trying to find more details on XMLGregorianCalendar, but the details everywhere is very cryptic.  It looks like the default format of XMLGregorianCalendar is yyyy-dd-mm.

My requirement is to change the format to mm-dd-yyyy , but no matter what i do i am unable to convert the format . Can some one help ?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.reedmace.net/how-to-convert-datetime-string-to-xml-date-without-timezone-or-fractional-seconds/

Check this solution may be it will help you.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
     try
    {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = sdf.format(new Date());
        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(date);

        String mm = String.valueOf( xmlCal.getMonth() );
        String dd = String.valueOf( xmlCal.getDay() );
        String yyyy = String.valueOf( xmlCal.getYear() );

        System.out.println( mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy );

    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( e );
    }
}
```

Check **getMonth() , getDay() , getYear()**

**Finally check this link**
[xmlgregoriancalendar formatting in MM/dd/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031903/xmlgregoriancalendar-formatting-in-mm-dd-yyyy)

Comment: I tested the code   but it defaults to yyyy-mm-dd.I tried changing some of the params but then it fails to create valid value

Comment: check changes in my answer ..It may be what you want

Comment: the code snippet prints the date in the format   mm-dd-yyyy..  While i want the XMLGregorianCalendar  object to be in the format mm-dd-yyyy.

 this field is set as XMLGregorianCalendar  in the XML request and we need to send it mm-dd-yyyy format 

I doubt if the XMLGregorianCalendar   can be saved in any format other than yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031903/xmlgregoriancalendar-formatting-in-mm-dd-yyyy